# error on loading json data

Tags: ajax, json

I am trying to load `.json` data into my web app and it never can achieve success.

It always returns the error function.

Here is my `.js` file:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var output = $('#stage');

 $.ajax({
     url: 'http://www.haverhill-ps.org/ios/app/data/calendar-json.json',
     dataType: 'json',
     timeout: 5000,
     success: function (data) {
         $.each(data, function (i, item) {
             var eventInfo = '<h1>' + item.month + '</h1>' + '<p>' + item.date + '<br>' + item.time + '</p>';

             output.append(eventInfo);
         });
     },
     error: function () {
         output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
     }
 });
});
```

Here is the `json` data:

```
{
    "month": "June", //November
    "date": "10", //10
    "time": "5PM", //5PM
}, {
    "month": "July", //November
    "date": "4", //10
    "time": "1PM", //5PM
}
```

Then, within my html I have a div setup:

```
<div id="stage">Run here...</div>
```

Comment: Good that you take care of error Handling. Now you should get the error message. Are you working on www.haverhill-ps.org or is it a 3rd party website ?

Comment: You're most probably encountering a cross-domain problem, you can't request data from a different domain without a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the returned data is not valid json.

your are missing `[`and `]`  around the result and comments are not valid in json.
the `,` at the end of the last element of each object is also invalid. you can validate your json at e.g. http://jsonlint.com/

a valid json would look this way:

```
[{
    "month": "June",
    "date": "10",
    "time": "5PM"
}, {
    "month": "July",
    "date": "4",
    "time": "1PM"
}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to using json so I appreciate that very much. It is amazing how a simple problem can cause such headaches. :)

Comment: @jons: no problem. validating your output or code should always be the first step. for js you can use _jslint_ or _jshint_. and json as i have already said with e.g. http://jsonlint.com/.

Answer (score 0):

May be you would like to see what is the error, do it this way

```
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }
```